# What to do after being phished for address, DOB and NI number?

Tags: phishing

When someone has given away their details as above, can anything be done to preemptively prevent identity theft?

Address, date of birth and national insurance number are obviously not passwords that can be changed.

Comment: @DanielGrover advocating illegal activity is not permitted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

National Insurance number suggests you are UK based. For protection from financial fraud you would go for protective registration with CIFAS and ask the three credit agencies (Equifax, Experian and Callcredit) to put notes on your files that all loan applications should be checked with you.

Most serious identity matters which do not use credit agencies will ask to see photo-id proof such as a passport or driving license. For passports these are hard to replace without holding the previous document - it often involves being called in for an in person interview - which offers some protection against fraud. Obviously if you have never held a passport before there is higher risk. Driving licenses are easier to obtain fraudulently. However the DVLA will use your passport photo if available - so it is still difficult to obtain one with an image of someone else.

Other nations have other systems. But in most places there is some form of credit agency which can be notified. Some countries (Estonia for example) use electronic ID cards.

Comment: Yes, we are in the UK. Is it possible to notify the DVLA in the same way as CIFAS? Also, will protection on CIFAS affect ability to get a mortgage etc (assuming the mortgage application is legitimate and authorized)?